# merging in git post-receive hook

Tags: git, githooks

I use the following post-receive hook:

```
GIT_TOP=`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`

while read oldrev newrev refname
do
        echo "=== $oldrev"
        echo "=== $newrev"
        echo "=== $refname"

        echo "=== 01. checkout -- $GIT_TOP/*"
        git checkout -- "$GIT_TOP/*"

        echo "=== 02. merging $refname"
        git merge $refname

        echo "=== 03. checkout -- $GIT_TOP/*"
        git checkout -- "$GIT_TOP/*"

done
```

The idea is clear enough: I want the current branch to be merged with a pushed one.

- Then I execute: `git status` and it show me that my local tree differs from the branch!
- Than I execute ones more `git checkout -- *` in the top of git dir - and now this command do what I want: `git status` shows now no differences anymore.

Why this command `git checkout -- "$GIT_TOP/*"` didn't work in hook, and works only by direct call? How to run this command in hook?

P.S.

I've found that `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` called from within the hook returns `<myrepo>/.git` path, but from the shell  its value is just `<myrepo>`. May be this can help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`export GIT_WORK_TREE=$GIT_DIR/.` solved my problem. Now even `git checkout -- "$GIT_TOP/*"` needn't anymore. Because `git merge $refname` works correctly - on the correct dir.

Comment: Would you mind updating the question to contain the final version? :) Or this answer rather and then marking it as the resolution?

Answer (score 3):

OK, Got it working now.  More thinking less copying.

```
export GIT_WORK_TREE=`pwd`
export GIT_DIR=`pwd`/.git
```

Paul

Answer (score 1):

Thx for this.

I tried this:

```
export GIT_WORK_TREE=$GIT_DIR/.
while read oldrev newrev refname
do
        echo "=== merging $refname"
        git merge $refname
done
```

got back error: "Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge"
.. mentioning the file just pushed.

This suggests that it not trying to merge the just-received change into the master branch

Maybe that checkout master was needed?

I was able to do the merge manually.

Paul